# cannot login to magento frontend and backend in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, magento

Users can not login to Magento frontend and even in backend on Internet explorer all other browsers working fine.

I searched on google found some solution related cookie time and adding tag on head 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`, but these all are useless.

How to fix this problem? 
please help.

Comment: It must be cookie issue with ie Browser

Comment: I enabled all cookies but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

## First login into your account with another browser (Chrome or Mozilla) then:

1. Go to System => Configuration => Web (under the tab General)
2. Under the section "Session Cookies Management" set the following parameters:

   - Cookie Lifetime: 0
   - Cookie Path: /
   - Cookie Domain: (leave it empty very important)
   - Use HTTP Only: **YES** (very important)
   - Cookie Restriction Mode: NO
3. Then open your Magento Admin page on Internet Explorer and now try to login, it should works.

That's it, I suggest you save first your parameters with a snapshot to remember if you need to put it back. Hope it helps.